# How to remove last-sixth word from the java string

Tags: java, string

I have few string that something looks like:

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";

String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";

String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";

String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
```

Now I want to remove the last-sixth word out of all of the above strings so that my result string should be:

```
Car is unknown in the system
Car is unknown in the system
New Car is unknown in the system
Very old car is unknown in the system
```

I just want to remove the carXXXX from the string. Is there a one line or elegant solution ?

Comment: How do you define what a word is?

Comment: transform it into an array of strings, by using split, and rebuild the string, by just leaving the second out

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String::replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

```java
System.out.println("Car honda3454 is unknown in the system".replaceFirst("(\\w+\\s+)(\\w+\\s*)", "$1"));
```

or [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) with an anchor `^` to the beginning of the input string:

```java
System.out.println("Car honda3454 is unknown in the system".replaceAll("^(\\w+\\s+)(\\w+\\s*)", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
Car is unknown in the system
Car is unknown in the system
```

---

**Update**
To remove the words *after* the word `"car"` written in any case in any place of the input string, the following regular expression may be used with `String::replaceAll`:
`str.replaceAll("(?i)(car\\W+)(\\w+\\W*)", "$1")`
here:

- `(?i)`: ignores case so that `car`, `Car`, `CAR` should be handled as is
- `(car\\W+)(\\w+\\W*)` - similar as before: find a sequence of two words where the first one is `car` followed by any word containing at least one letter or digit due to `\w` character class.
- `"$1"` - the replacement string is the first matched word of the two.

So the following test using an array produces relevant output:

```java
String[] strs = {
    "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system",
    "CAR BMW4545 is unknown in the system",
    "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system",
    "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system"
};

for (String s : strs) {
    // a new string is created and printed, the value in the array remains unchanged
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)(car\\W+)(\\w+\\W*)", "$1"));
}
```

Output:

```
Car is unknown in the system
CAR is unknown in the system
New Car is unknown in the system
Very old car is unknown in the system
```

Comment: If you're using `\w` to detect word characters, you might want to use `\W` to detect non-word characters, rather than assuming it will be whitespace. (Or, `\s` and `\S`, perhaps)

Comment: Can you please be so kind and help me in finding the solution of the new problem stated above

Answer (score 1):

Easy and undestandable way for beginners:

```
public class Main {
public static void main() {
    String input = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
    String carName = input.split(" ")[1]; //get the second word
    String output = input.replace(carName, "").replace("  ", " "); //delete the second word by replacing, delete double spaces

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please be so kind and help me in finding the solution of the new problem stated above

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
String str = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String [] words = str.split(" ", 3);
for (String word : words)
System.out.println(word);



Output
--------------------
Car is unknown in the system
```

Comment: Can you please be so kind and help me in finding the solution of the new problem stated above

Answer (score 0):

There are several strange examples in the other answers, laborious or that stick to a specific word in the sentence in order to find the one you want. If you want a more dynamic alternative, you can use regex and replace.

The simplest I can imagine is using replace with the `([^\s]+)(?=(\s[^\s]+){5}$)` regex. Try:

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";

System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str2.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str3.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str4.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
```

**(Edit)**
If you also want to remove the space character, so as not to have an extra blank character, use `\S+\s+(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`. (@s19 pointed out this case in his answer, but the solution proposed by him does not meet all scenarios, as in the additional I included below)

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
String strAdditional = "mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
        
String regex = "\\S+\\s+(?=(\\S+\\s+){4}\\S+\\s*$)";
        
System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str2.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str3.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str4.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(strAdditional.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
```

### Explanation:

I will use the `\S+\s+(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)` regex as an example. It is divided into two parts:

- The *Match* `\S+\s+`, which represents the content you are trying to capture.
- The *Positive Lookahead* `(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`, which represents a rule that needs to be met, but will not select characters.

**Detailing the first part we have: `\S+\s+`**

- `\S` selecting any character that does not represent a white space (can be numbers, letters, symbols, etc).
- `+`, which is linked to the previous selector, defining that it will have to appear at least once, and can be repeated infinite times. This guarantees a string of characters.
- `\s` selects any character that represents a white space (can be tabs, line breaks, white space, etc).
- `+` has the same function as above, but this time allows for multiple whitespace.

Hence, `\S+` selects any character representing a sequence of characters until it is interrupted by one (or a sequence of) whitespace `\s+`.

**Detailing the second part: `(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`**

- `(?=)` encompasses all this part and is called Positive Lookahead. It indicates that the set of rules contained here needs to be met, but that this text will not be selected.
- `(\S+\s+){4}` again indicates a string that can represent a word until it is interrupted by whitespace. The difference is that this time it is contained within a group delimited by `()`, and that group must be repeated 4 times `{4}`, which means 4 words.
- `\S+\s*` is almost the same as the first part, with the difference that this is the last word, and it may or may not contain any whitespace characters after it. The `*` after `\s` means that any number of blank characters can be met by the rule, even if there are none.
- `$` is an anchor representing the end of the text. It indicates that this rule must be, in some ways, analyzed from the end to the beginning of the text.

Hence, `$` indicates that it should be counted from the end; `\S+\s*` counts the last word, which may or may not contain whitespace after it; `(\S+\s+){4}` counts four words before the last; and everything is encompassed by `(?=)`, which forces you to comply with these rules but which does not select the text that matches them.

---

Here is an online example explaining how the regex works: https://regex101.com/r/Lvzog2/1

Comment: It really depends on the use case if that regexp approach is needed here. If author wants to use that just for cars then I would stick with simpler logic.

Answer (score 0):

Edu Muller's answer is close but it results in an additional whitespace in place of the removed word as shown below:

Car   is unknown in the system
Car   is unknown in the system
New Car   is unknown in the system
Very old car   is unknown in the system

The below code resolves this issue.

```
static String removeLastSixth(String input) {
return input.replaceFirst("(\\s)([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", "");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
    String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
    String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
    String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
    System.out.println(removeLastSixth(str1));     
    System.out.println(removeLastSixth(str2));      
    System.out.println(removeLastSixth(str3));      
    System.out.println(removeLastSixth(str4));      

}
```

### Output

Car is unknown in the system
Car is unknown in the system
New Car is unknown in the system
Very old car is unknown in the system

---

The above solution removes sixth word from the last. But if you want to remove the word following the word 'car' irrespective of it's position, use the below function.

```
static String removeWordFollowingCar(String input) {
    return input.replaceFirst("(?i)(Car\\s+)(\\w+\\s)", "$1");
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "The Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
    String str2 = "Hi, the Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
    String str3 = "Hey, unfortunately the New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
    String str4 = "Hello, this Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
    System.out.println(removeWordFollowingCar(str1));     
    System.out.println(removeWordFollowingCar(str2));      
    System.out.println(removeWordFollowingCar(str3));      
    System.out.println(removeWordFollowingCar(str4));      

}
```

### Output

The Car is unknown in the system
Hi, the Car is unknown in the system
Hey, unfortunately the New Car is unknown in the system
Hello, this Very old car is unknown in the system