# How to remove the last-sixth word from sentence

Tags: java, regex, string

I have few string that something looks like:

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";

String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";

String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";

String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
```

Now I want to remove the last-sixth word out of all of the above strings so that my result string should be:

```
Car is unknown in the system
Car is unknown in the system
New Car is unknown in the system
Very old car is unknown in the system
```

I just want to remove the carXXXX from the string. Is there a one line or elegant solution ?

Comment: Doesn't need further clarity.  I think the community got this close wrong.

Comment: Also, this is an exact copy of your previous question, posted 10 minutes apart, with the only difference being one tag. Please edit existing questions to make changes like that instead of posting duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove last-sixth word from the java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030194/how-to-remove-last-sixth-word-from-the-java-string)

Comment: She wants obviously to remove the 6th word counted from the end of the sentence.

Comment: @user16320675 Yeah and it is the 6th word from the end in your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest I can imagine is using replace with the `([^\s]+)(?=(\s[^\s]+){5}$)` regex. Try:

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";

System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str2.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str3.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
System.out.println(str4.replaceFirst("([^\\s]+)(?=(\\s[^\\s]+){5}$)", ""));
```

**(Edit)**
If you also want to remove the space character, so as not to have an extra blank character, use `\S+\s+(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`.

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String str2 = "Car BMW4545 is unknown in the system";
String str3 = "New Car Audi9898 is unknown in the system";
String str4 = "Very old car mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
String strAdditional = "mitsubishi4099 is unknown in the system";
        
String regex = "\\S+\\s+(?=(\\S+\\s+){4}\\S+\\s*$)";
        
System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str2.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str3.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(str4.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
System.out.println(strAdditional.replaceFirst(regex, ""));
```

### Explanation:

I will use the `\S+\s+(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)` regex as an example. It is divided into two parts:

- The *Match* `\S+\s+`, which represents the content you are trying to capture.
- The *Positive Lookahead* `(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`, which represents a rule that needs to be met, but will not select characters.

**Detailing the first part we have: `\S+\s+`**

- `\S` selecting any character that does not represent a white space (can be numbers, letters, symbols, etc).
- `+`, which is linked to the previous selector, defining that it will have to appear at least once, and can be repeated infinite times. This guarantees a string of characters.
- `\s` selects any character that represents a white space (can be tabs, line breaks, white space, etc).
- `+` has the same function as above, but this time allows for multiple whitespace.

Hence, `\S+` selects any character representing a sequence of characters until it is interrupted by one (or a sequence of) whitespace `\s+`.

**Detailing the second part: `(?=(\S+\s+){4}\S+\s*$)`**

- `(?=)` encompasses all this part and is called Positive Lookahead. It indicates that the set of rules contained here needs to be met, but that this text will not be selected.
- `(\S+\s+){4}` again indicates a string that can represent a word until it is interrupted by whitespace. The difference is that this time it is contained within a group delimited by `()`, and that group must be repeated 4 times `{4}`, which means 4 words.
- `\S+\s*` is almost the same as the first part, with the difference that this is the last word, and it may or may not contain any whitespace characters after it. The `*` after `\s` means that any number of blank characters can be met by the rule, even if there are none.
- `$` is an anchor representing the end of the text. It indicates that this rule must be, in some ways, analyzed from the end to the beginning of the text.

Hence, `$` indicates that it should be counted from the end; `\S+\s*` counts the last word, which may or may not contain whitespace after it; `(\S+\s+){4}` counts four words before the last; and everything is encompassed by `(?=)`, which forces you to comply with these rules but which does not select the text that matches them.

---

Here is an online example explaining how the regex works: https://regex101.com/r/Lvzog2/1

Comment: there are extra space characters and thats why it fails to check

Comment: @Sandra I added another regex that removes the extra character together. I also included one more line as a test case. If it still doesn't solve your problem, please provide more details about possible inputs and desired outputs. If so, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Hello, It works fine and I marked it as accepted. Could you please kind and explain how this regex works in detail ?

Comment: @Sandra I've included an explanation, as well as changing the last regex to something simpler, but that works the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the word that needs to be removed is always sixth-to-last you can try this:

```
String str1 = "Car honda3454 is unknown in the system";
String new_str=editString(str1);

public static String editString(String str){
  String s="";
  String[] tokens=str.split(" ");
  for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;++i){
    if(i!=(tokens.length-6)){
      s+=tokens[i]+" ";
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```